# How to check if the native/hardware keyboard is used?

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, soft-keyboard, android-keypad

I want to check if the native/hardware keyboard is used, and also if possible I want to disable the third party keyboards.

My goal is simple I use just the native android soft keyboard for entering values in my edit boxes and no other keyboard should be able to this

Thanks

**EDIT**

I know it is not good idea to do what I am trying to do, I know that the basic idea of android is to have  intents and activities and services who know to handle some types of intent according intent-filter. But this in every rule there is an exception, especially when we talk about security.

I want to disable all third party keyboards, and if this is not possible to do it with some API or something... is there any workaround to this problem ?

**EDIT**

```
String s=Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

This returns the currently enabled input method (keyboard),but I need something like the 'system keyboard' and I do not see any flag like that :-(.

```
List<InputMethodInfo> list = m.getInputMethodList();
```

One possible solution is to take the list[0] as the keyboard I am searching, but I do not want to relay on the order (except if the order is garanteed that always the keyboard with index 0 is the one that comes install with the phone)

this is the value of list

```
[InputMethodInfo{com.htc.android.htcime/.HTCIMEService, settings: com.htc.android.htcime.HTCIMESettings}, InputMethodInfo{com.volosyukivan/.WiFiInputMethod, settings: null}]
```

Comment: Why? By 'native' do you mean the one that comes installed on the device when you purchase it? because that is potentially different for each device. Are you trying to ensure that the keyboard the user is using doesn't track passwords?

Comment: Yes I mean the one that comes installed with the device, I guess the 'native' it is not the correct expression,tnx for the correction

Comment: Maybe you can get `Default Input Method` and compare the result , maybe u van try look at here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Comment: Not a good idea. If it were possible, users would not be happy being forced to change their system settings just to accommodate your app. One of the great things about Android is not being constrained to using the default of anything.

Comment: yes the will not be happy, but they will be much more unhappy if you let their secure data to be corrupt... They take my app because they want all the back doors to be disable, if the want a fancy keyboard to be used they will uninstall my app...

Comment: The discussion is if this is possible and how to do it, not if I should do it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check if the native/hardware keyboard is used

You can use the `Configuration` object to see if the device's hardware keyboard is hidden. Usually, that would imply they are using that keyboard, since most devices do not show an IME when the hardware keyboard is available. However, some devices might support both simultaneously, and I don't know how external keyboards (USB, Bluetooth) interact with this value.

> also if possible I want to disable the third party keyboards.

Fortunately, this is not possible.

> is there any workaround to this problem ?

There is no problem cited to this point in the question.

> yes the will not be happy, but they will be much more unhappy if you let their secure data to be corrupt

If users choose to use an alternative keyboard, that is their choice as users. The user is perfectly capable of switching keyboards if they wish. The user is perfectly capable of making these decisions. It is entirely possible that an alternative keyboard is *more* secure than a built-in one, due to devices loaded with spyware from the factor, such as [CarrierIQ](http://androidsecuritytest.com/features/logs-and-services/loggers/carrieriq/). Hence, your assumption that you are improving security by attacking the user's choice of keyboard is fundamentally flawed.

Of course, you do not have to support using any keyboard at all, forcing users to use some sort of on-screen input option that you devise yourself. This is not completely secure either (e.g., tapjacking attacks), and it may cause usability problems for people who chose certain third-party keyboards for specific reasons (e.g., blind users, users with motor control issues).

I am not aware that there is a way to definitively determine what the firmware's own IME is, particularly since this varies by device and firmware.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should let you check if the user is using a non-standard keyboard. However, instead of preventing them using this keyboard, how about a helpful warning message about the possible security risks?

```
public boolean isUsingCustomInputMethod() {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mCtx.getSystemService(
        Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    List<InputMethodInfo> mInputMethodProperties = imm.getEnabledInputMethodList();
    final int N = mInputMethodProperties.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        InputMethodInfo imi = mInputMethodProperties.get(i);
        if (imi.getId().equals(
            Settings.Secure.getString(mCtx.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD))) {
            if ((imi.getServiceInfo().applicationInfo.flags & 
                ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: this works.. but for some reason Swype is detected as a standard keyboard.  not what I wanted.. but that doesnt mean it's wrong.

Comment: @LouMorda:Do you mind sharing how to figured out if swype is being used?

Comment: It works after a couple of changes. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I find precise solution

```
InputMethodManager m = (InputMethodManager) ctx.getSystemService("input_method");
List<InputMethodInfo> a = m.getInputMethodList();
for (InputMethodInfo inputMethodInfo : a) {
        if (inputMethodInfo.getIsDefaultResourceId() == 0) {
            //it is not default
            return false;
        }
}
//it is default
return true;
```