# How to detect if user's keyboard is Swype?

Tags: android, keyboard, ime

Is it possible to know the keyboard being used by the user? How do I check if the user is using a Swype keyboard?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can retrieve the current default keyboard using:

```
String currentKeyboard =  Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.DEFAULT_INPUT_METHOD);
```

You will get a result like `com.touchtype.swiftkey/com.touchtype.KeyboardService` for various keyboards. The first part is the main package name of the keyboard, and the second is the name of the Keyboard Service it uses. Simply parse this String to see if it matches the info for Swype (I can only provide SwiftKey's details right now, as I don't have Swype installed).

Comment: Thanks! :) I got it now! Without the explanation and assignment of the variable, I thought the code is for selecting what keyboard is going to be used.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8165618/how-to-check-if-the-native-hardware-keyboard-is-used/12557231#12557231

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your answer is here:

[How to determine the current IME in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744729/how-to-determine-the-current-ime-in-android)

Sometimes it's just about knowing the right search term.

Comment: And here is everything else: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure.html

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I tried to search for it but it seems that I'm not using the correct keyword. I want to set your answer as the correct answer but Raghav also posted the answer here with explanation.

Comment: Completeness wins the day. That's fair. Thanks for the upvote (I assume ti's from you) in any case.

Answer (score 2):

The following lets you determine if Samsung, Google, or Swype keyboard is used.

```
public boolean usingSamsungKeyboard(Context context){
    return usingKeyboard(context, "com.sec.android.inputmethod/.SamsungKeypad");
}

public boolean usingSwypeKeyboard(Context context){
    return usingKeyboard(context, "com.nuance.swype.input/.IME");
}

public boolean usingGoogleKeyboard(Context context){
    return usingKeyboard(context, "com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME");
}   

public boolean usingKeyboard(Context context, String keyboardId)
    {
        final InputMethodManager richImm =
          (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        boolean isKeyboard = false;

        final Field field;
        try
        {
            field = richImm.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCurId");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object value = field.get(richImm);
            isKeyboard = value.equals(keyboardId);

        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e)
        {

        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e)
        {

        }
        return  isKeyboard;
    }
```